# Write out specific ranges in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following problem:

I have several values like ABD and then at the end i have (0-9; A-Z) defining the range.
So if you write it out it's ABD0; ABD1;... ABDY; ABDZ.

I have two table structures:
[image]

How can i write out the ranges for both table structures (view them as separate) with formula or VBA code?
SO that i have all the ranges written out like ABD0; ABD1;... ABDY; ABDZ.

Thanks in advance.

Updated Picture:
[image]

Next Picture:
[image]

Update 3:

[image]

Comment: Will it always be `(0-9; A-Z)` - or might this change?

Comment: What's your XL version to make a formula?

Comment: It will not always be like that @Ike it might change

Comment: What could be other other options? I think you need to be clearer/more precise regarding the requirements

Comment: The other options could be everyting in the 0-9 to A-Z range, e.g. (3-8); (F-M)

Comment: Are you using Excel 365? This makes a big difference as there are a lot of new formulas

Comment: So, do you like a solution to **write in a `Range` 'ABD0, ABD1, ABD2, ..., ABDA, ABDB ... ABDZ` for "0-9;A-Z"**? And **'ABD3, ABD4 ... ABD8 ... ABDA, ABDB, ... ABDM` for "3-8;A-M"**? Is such an understanding a correct one?

Comment: @FaneDuru Exactly, depending on what is in between the brackets.

Comment: @Ike yes, im using excel 365

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. But I would like to ask you if not enough convenient to **avoid using `0` in the range `0-9`** and use `1` and even exceeding the range as **`1-20`**?

Comment: @FaneDuru Im sorry but it wont fulfill its purpose without the 0.

Comment: @dani2507 have you got to try my solution with formulas?

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next VBA code:

```
Sub WriteRangeSeries()
  Dim x As String, strPref As String, strCond As String, arrCond, strRow As String, strCol As String
  Dim arrRow, arrCol, arrNumb() As String, arrLetters() As String, arrRng() As String, bool0 As Boolean
  
    x = "ABD(0-11;A-Z)"
    strPref = left(x, InStr(x, "(") - 1) 'extract prefix before "(" - ABD, in this case
    strCond = Mid(x, Len(strPref) + 2)
    strCond = left(strCond, Len(strCond) - 1)           'extract conditions to be processed (numbers and letters ranges)
    arrCond = Split(Replace(strCond, " ", ""), ";")  'just for the case of spaces existing as: 0 - 11;A-Z, 0-11; A-Z, 0-11;A- Z
    arrRow = Split(arrCond(0), "-"): If arrRow(0) = "0" Then arrRow(0) = "1": bool0 = True 'replace 0 with 1 in case of its existing as the first digit
     strRow = Join(arrRow, ":") 'create the string to be evaluated as transposed rows
      
    arrCol = Split(arrCond(1), "-"): arrCol(0) = Asc(arrCol(0)): arrCol(1) = Asc(arrCol(1))
      strCol = Join(arrCol, ":")
    
    arrNumb = Split(strPref & Join(Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & strRow & ")-" & IIf(bool0, 1, 0) & ")"), "|" & strPref), "|")
    Debug.Print Join(arrNumb, "|") 'just to visually see the joined created array
   
    arrLetters = Split(strPref & Join(Evaluate("CHAR(TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & strCol & ")))"), "|" & strPref), "|")
    Debug.Print Join(arrLetters, "|") 'just to visually see the joined created array
    arrRng = Split(Join(arrNumb, "|") & "|" & Join(arrLetters, "|"), "|")

    'drop the built array content, starting from "A2". You can choose this cell as you need/wont:
    Range("A2").Resize(1, UBound(arrRng) + 1).Value2 = arrRng
End Sub
```

Dis is the didactic approach, a little easier to be understood...

You can use it as a function:

```
Function createRangeArr(x As String) As String()
  Dim strPref As String, strCond As String, arrCond, strRow As String, strCol As String
  Dim arrRow, arrCol, arrNumb() As String, arrLetters() As String, arrRng() As String, bool0 As Boolean
  
    
    strPref = left(x, InStr(x, "(") - 1) 'extract prefix before "(" - ABD, in this case
    strCond = Mid(x, Len(strPref) + 2)
    strCond = left(strCond, Len(strCond) - 1)           'extract conditions to be processed (numbers and letters ranges)
    arrCond = Split(Replace(strCond, " ", ""), ";")  'just for the case of spaces existing as: 0 - 11;A-Z, 0-11; A-Z, 0-11;A- Z
    arrRow = Split(arrCond(0), "-"): If arrRow(0) = "0" Then arrRow(0) = "1": bool0 = True 'replace 0 with 1 in case of its existing as the first digit
     strRow = Join(arrRow, ":") 'create the string to be evaluated as transposed rows
      
    arrCol = Split(arrCond(1), "-"): arrCol(0) = Asc(arrCol(0)): arrCol(1) = Asc(arrCol(1)) 'replace the letters with their ASCII value
      strCol = Join(arrCol, ":")   'create the string to be evaluated
      
    'create the array involving numbers:
    arrNumb = Split(strPref & Join(Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & strRow & ")-" & IIf(bool0, 1, 0) & ")"), "|" & strPref), "|")
    'create the array involving letters:
    arrLetters = Split(strPref & Join(Evaluate("CHAR(TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & strCol & ")))"), "|" & strPref), "|")
    
    createRangeArr = Split(Join(arrNumb, "|") & "|" & Join(arrLetters, "|"), "|") 'make the array by splitting the above joined arrays
End Function
```

And can be used in the next way:

```
Sub testCreateRange()
    Dim x As String, arrRng() As String, rngFirstCell As Range
    
    x = "ABD(0-11;A-Z)"
    Set rngFirstCell = Range("A2")
    arrRng = createRangeArr(x)
    rngFirstCell.Resize(1, UBound(arrRng) + 1).Value2 = arrRng
End Sub
```

Or using it as UDF, placing the next formula in a cell:

```
  =createRangeArr(A1)
```

Of course, in A1 (or somewhere else) must be the string to be evaluated (ABD(0-11;A-Z))...

**Edited**:

In order to build the string to be evaluated from two cells value, you can simple use (as UDF) formula:

```
   =createRangeArr(A1&A2)
```

Of course, A1 and A2 will keep partial strings to build the necesssary one...

And in case of calling the function from VBA, you can use:

```
   arrRng = createRangeArr(Range("A1").value & Range("A2").value)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Is there a way to "automate it for all combinations i have? Like defining the initial variable x as the combination of the first the letters with the range in another cell? And then just post the results for all of those instances? Ill update the picture in the main post

Comment: @dani2507 If I would understand what you mean, probably yes... But I cannot get you. So, instead of having the string to be evaluated ("ABD(0-11;A-Z") in a cell, do you want using a concatenation between two cells? One containing "ABD" and the other one "(0-11;A-Z)?"? Is that what you mean? If not, please be more specific. Some examples will probably help, too...

Comment: @dani2507 Please, see the updated answer (after **Edited**) and give it a try. And send some feedback after testing it... Do you want a solution for processing that four cases shown in the updated question picture? It is easy. Just saying where to be returned the range in discussion. Starting from C:C column?

Comment: Thank you, i updated the picture aswell. If i use it as a function, i can just simply drop down and excel automatically updates the(A1&2), right? Is there a way for the output to also match the same row or colum? So it doesn override the previous results?

Comment: @dani2507  "=A1&A2", as formula... Or `Range("A1").Value & Range("A2").value` in case of calling it from VBA. I cannot understand what you mean by **dropping down** and by **output to also match the same row or column**... Do you mean to return on a column instead of a row?

Comment: @dani2507 Do you mean to `FillDown` the formula?

Comment: I just tried using it as a formula, however it only outputs one result in my case ABD0 and nothing more. It would be perfect if i used the formula and then dragged it down like you do with normal formulas so it uses the formula again ond the new set of ranges.

Comment: I think filldown is what i mean, yes.

Comment: @dani2507 It should be working. But "=A1&A2" was only an example... If you place the formula in C:C column you should use **"=A1&B1"**. I tested and it works as it should... If there are values **in columns after C:C** it will not overwrite them! You should manually clear the range to make space for the function return...

Comment: I posted a 3rd picture, which explains what happens to me. It shows that theres only 1 result except for the whole range of results it should put out. Im sorry if this seems very mundane to you.

Comment: @dani2507 I can see the picture but I cannot understand  what you mean... Do you have AnyDesc installed on your computer? Without seeing what's happening in your case I cannot understand what you show... I wrote above: **If there are values in columns after C:C it will not overwrite them!**. Did you take care about this aspect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248252/discussion-between-dani2507-and-faneduru).

Comment: @FaneDuru Admire your perseverance & creativity ("virtual ranges"); 'ed :-) FYi might be interested in my late post, too.

Comment: @dani2507 I would like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=LET(C,A2,D,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(C,"("),")",""),"-",";"),";"),T,TEXTBEFORE(C,"("),VSTACK(T&CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT(CODE(INDEX(D,1))&":"&CODE(INDEX(D,2))))),IFERROR(T&CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT(CODE(INDEX(D,3))&":"&CODE(INDEX(D,4))))),"")))
```

Change `A2` with your cell reference

edit
modified to include more than 1 digit and more than 1 alphabetic char

```
=LET(C,A2,D,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(C,"("),")",""),"-",";"),";"),T,TEXTBEFORE(C,"("),VSTACK(T&SEQUENCE(INDEX(D,2)-INDEX(D,1)+1,1,INDEX(D,1)),T&IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,SEQUENCE(COLUMN(INDIRECT(INDEX(D,4)&"1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT(INDEX(D,3)&"1"))+1,1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(INDEX(D,3)&"1"))),4),"1",""),"")))
```

I've seen your new request and this is to expand horizontally from two cells

```
=LET(C,SUBSTITUTE(A2&B2;" ";""),D,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(C,"("),")",""),"-",";"),";"),T,TEXTBEFORE(C,"("),TRANSPOSE(VSTACK(T&SEQUENCE(INDEX(D,2)-INDEX(D,1)+1,1,INDEX(D,1)),T&IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,SEQUENCE(COLUMN(INDIRECT(INDEX(D,4)&"1"))-COLUMN(INDIRECT(INDEX(D,3)&"1"))+1,1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(INDEX(D,3)&"1"))),4),"1",""),""))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Disposing of Excel/MS 365 and the new `TextSplit()` function you might profit from
the following blockwise calculation of array results.

**Note** that I assumed the entire code inputs in column `A` only - *it would be relatively easy, however to change the procedure also for the case of code inputs in two separate columns `A:B` as mentioned by Dani as further possible input option*.

```
Sub TxtSplit()
    Const colOffset As Long = 3             ' column offset for target
    Const colCount  As Long = 36            ' 10 nums + 26 chars = 36
    With Sheet1                     ' << change to wanted Project's sheet Code(Name)
    '1. define data range containing codes      ' e.g. "ABD(0-3;M-N)", etc.
        Dim lastrow As Long
        lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)  ' << define start row as needed
    '2. get codes
        Dim codes: codes = rng.Value        ' variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array
    '3. clear target (e.g. 3 columns to the right)
        rng.Offset(, colOffset).Resize(, colCount) = vbNullString
    '4. calculate results and write them to range offset
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(codes)           ' << Loop
        'a) get definitions elements
            Dim defs                             ' 1   2 3 4 5
            defs = getDefs(codes(i, 1))          ' ABD|0|3|M|N|
        'b) get array elements with numeric and character suffixes
            Dim num:  num = getNum(defs)
            Dim char: char = getChars(defs)
        'c) write results to target (e.g. 3 columns to the right)
            With rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(i - 1, colOffset)
                .Resize(1, UBound(num)) = num
                .Offset(, UBound(num)).Resize(1, UBound(char)) = char
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Help functions**

- `getNums()`... calculating the items with numeric suffixes using a `Sequence()` evaluation
- `getChars()`.. calculating the items with character suffixes using a `Sequence()` evaluation
- `getDefs()`... tokenizing the code inputs via a `TextSplit()` evaluation (based on an array of delimiters)
- `col()`....... getting column numbers out of character inputs

```
Function getNum(x, Optional ByVal myFormula As String = "")
    myFormula = _
        """" & x(1) & """ &" & _
        "Sequence(" & Join(Array(1, x(3) - x(2) + 1, x(2)), ",") & ")"
    getNum = Evaluate(myFormula)
End Function
```

```
Function getChars(x, Optional ByVal myFormula As String = "")
    myFormula = _
        """" & x(1) & """ & " & _
        "Char(" & "Sequence(" & Join(Array(1, x(5) - x(4) + 1, x(4)), ",") & ")" & "+64)"
    getChars = Evaluate(myFormula)
End Function
```

```
Function getDefs(ByVal code As String, Optional ByVal myFormula As String = "")
'Purp: tokenize code string, e.g. ABD(0-3;M-N) ~~> ABD|0|3|M|N|
'a) split code into tokens (via array of delimiters)
    myFormula = "=TEXTSplit(""" & code & """,{""("","";"",""-"","")""})"
    Dim tmp: tmp = Evaluate(myFormula)          ' e.g. ABD|0|3|M|N|
'b) change column characters into numeric values
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 4 To 5: tmp(i) = col(tmp(i)): Next  ' col chars to nums
'c) return definitions
    getDefs = tmp
End Function
```

```
Function col(ByVal colChar As String) As Long
'Purp:  change column character to number
    col = Range(colChar & 1).Column
End Function
```

Comment: Nice... Voted up!